# Save / Update one to many Relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to update 1 to many relationship in laravel (below code only works for saving data but i want to update as well by pasing id of record in array)

Suggestions are most welcome!

Also let me know if any better solution you have for storing (1 to M)

Thanks in advance.

```
 public function saveUserAddress($request)
    {
        $user = $request->user();
        $addresses = $request->addresses;
            if(!empty($addresses)){
                for($i=0;$i < count($addresses['country_id']);$i++){
                    $id = $addresses['id'][$i] ?? 0;
                     $userAddressData[] = new UserAddress([
                         'country_id' =>  $addresses['country_id'][$i] ?? null,
                         'state_id' =>   $addresses['state_id'][$i] ?? null,
                         'city_id' =>$addresses['city_id'][$i] ?? null,
                         'type' =>$addresses['type'][$i] ?? null,
                         'address_line_1' =>$addresses['address_line_1'][$i] ?? null,
                         'address_line_2' =>$addresses['address_line_2'][$i] ?? null,
                         'phone' =>$addresses['phone'][$i] ?? null,
                         'postcode' =>$addresses['postcode'][$i] ?? null,
                     ]);
                   
            } 
            //$user->addresses()->updateOrCreate($userAddressData); // e.g  want to achieve this 
            $user->addresses()->saveMany($userAddressData);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe smth like that? `foreach($userAddressData as $userAddress){ $user->addresses()->updateOrCreate($userAddress) } `

Comment: I want this in 1 shot.. I dont want to execute multiple insert for same operation.

Comment: something like  $user->addresses()->updateOrSaveMany($userAddressData);

Comment: There is no such method or etc in Laravel yet. :(